# How to iterate over specific dates in a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, date, datetime, calendar

I have a large text document of datapoints (each "column" is separated by tabs) (>300,000 rows) from over the course of a month, with several column values including date/time and a unique ID code.

There are several instances of each ID code being used on each day, and I need to output the number of unique IDs for each day of the month.

So far, I import the text doc as a 2d array. I have a function that outputs a list of unique IDs used over a given time period, but I have not figured out how to select specific dates in the 'table'.

For a bit of info, the date/time values come in the format "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss". Below is a sample of my code.

Thanks for taking the time to read through.

```
  Array1 = np.genfromtxt('*Path*', delimiter="\t", dtype=(str))


def Unique_ID_Func():
    #Take the IDs column from the 2D array and turn it into a list.
    List_of_IDs = Array1[:,7].tolist()
    #Create a second list to input all of the unique IDs. Run through the first list and if the value is not already in the second list, add it in.
    Unique_IDs = []
    for IDs in List_of_IDs:
        if IDs not in Unique_IDs:
            Unique_IDs.append(IDs)  
    #print Unique_IDs
    print "The number of Unique IDs is ", len(Unique_IDs)
```